# The default table name of my table in SQL is table 2 and I cannot rename it

Tags: mysql, database

I converted an excel file into sql. I was not aware that it set a default name to my table and it is now called table 2. However table is a keyword. I want to rename it but I'm getting an error. I tried using different codes but none of these work.

```
RENAME TABLE table 2 to ProjectBlue;

ALTER TABLE table 2 RENAME ProjectBlue;

RENAME TABLE [table 2] to ProjectBlue;
```

Comment: Table name with space is not correct and you need to wrap inside backticks `` something as ALTER TABLE `table 2` RENAME ProjectBlue; Make sure table 2 is wrapped inside ``

Comment: ` <-- this is your friend